# Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Show that $ \frac{(m+n)!}{(m+n)^{m+n}} < \frac{m! n!}{m^m n^n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers. Show that 
>   $$\frac{(m+n)!}{(m+n)^{m + n}} < \frac{m! n!}{m^m n^n}.$$

I am not able to solve the problem. Is anyone is able to give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On one hand, $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ is a binomial coefficient in $(x+y)^{m+n}$. What choices of $x$ and $y$ are suitable to prove that this coefficient is smaller than $\frac{(m+n)^{m+n}}{m^mn^n}$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{(m+n)^{m+n}}{m^mn^n}=\left(\frac{m+n}{mn}\right)^{m+n}n^mm^n$$